# .Net Application to read timezone registry based on passed timezone language

Tags: c#, .net, timezone, registry, windows-server-2008

I am using a .net application where application reads the timezone and take the value from registry of the timezone from the server.

What issue I am facing is, Application tried to read registry for any non English timezone standard name (e.g. "Tokyo standard time" [**remember This string is in Japanese language**]) and to find the registry as registry having English language.

See below code snippet:

```
@"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Time Zones"))

foreach (TimeZoneInformation tzi in TimeZones)
{
    if (tzi.StandardName.ToLower() == timeZoneStandardName.ToLower())
    {
        //If Day light doesn't apply to given timezone then return standard offset
        //sb.AppendLine();
        //sb.AppendLine("========Matching Registry Foung ======");
        //sb.AppendLine("Timezone bias value : " + tzi.tzInfo.bias);
        if (tzi.tzInfo.daylightDate.wYear == 0 && tzi.tzInfo.daylightDate.wMonth == 0 && tzi.tzInfo.daylightDate.wDay == 0 &&
            tzi.tzInfo.daylightDate.wHour == 0 && tzi.tzInfo.daylightDate.wMinute == 0 && tzi.tzInfo.daylightDate.wSecond == 0)
        {
            //if offset positive then add bias

            if (isOffSetPositive)
            {
                date = date.AddMinutes(tzi.tzInfo.bias);
            }
            else
            {
                date = date.AddMinutes(-tzi.tzInfo.bias);
            }
            //sb.AppendLine("Updated DateTime value : "+ date.ToString());
            //ExceptionManager.LogInforamtion(sb.ToString());

            return;
        }
```

System configuration: 
**OS: Windows server 2008 R2 Standard**

**Base OS language: English [US]**

What I want is to get the Timezone registry name based on the application's timezone language.

Please feel free to ask related question I may have missed some useful information.

Answer (score 4):

A few things:

- You should not be inventing your own `TimeZoneInformation` class by reading from the registry.  Just use `System.TimeZoneInfo` which already does exactly that.
- You should match using the `Id` of the time zone, which is the same as the name of the registry key.  These are exact English strings and are never translated into other languages.  Don't match on `StandardName`.
- The `StandardName`, `DaylightName`, and `DisplayName` values are indeed localized, by the language of the operating system.  They don't participate in .NET globalization, and you can't get at them without installing language packs into the OS and switching to the other language.
- The way you're converting time with `AddMinutes` and trying to calculate from the bias alone is wrong on many levels.   Don't write that code.  Just use the `ConvertTime` and related functions from the `TimeZoneInfo` class.
- For an alternative approach and better localization, you might consider using [Noda Time](http://nodatime.org/) and [TimeZoneNames](http://mj1856.github.io/TimeZoneNames/) libraries.